# How to use fold to do boolean testing

Tags: scala, datetime, fold

I'd like to know the idiomatic way to approach this problem in scala.

Given a start date and an end date and a collection of dates in between, determine whether the given collection of dates contains all the dates necessary to go from the start date to the end date with no gap dates in between.

Type signature:

`def checkDate(start: DateTime, end: DateTime, between: IndexedSeq[DateTime]): Boolean`

The "normal" or "not functional" way to do this would be something like this:

```
def checkDate(start: DateTime, end: DateTime, between: IndexedSeq[DateTime]): Boolean = {
  i = 1
  status = true
  while(start != end) {
    d = start.plusDays(i)
    if (!between.contains(d) {
      status = false
      break
    }
    i += 1
  }
  return status
}
```

How can I do this using a Fold?

Here's my thought process so far:

```
def checkDate(start: DateTime, end: DateTime, between: IndexedSeq[DateTime]): Boolean = {

  // A fold will assume the dates are in order and move left (or right)
  // This means the dates must be sorted.
  val sorted = between.sortBy(_.getMillis())

  val a = sorted.foldLeft(List[Boolean]) {
    (acc, current) => {
      // How do I access an iterable version of the start date?
      if (current == ??) {
        acc :: true
      } else false
    }
  }

  // If the foldLeft produced any values that could NOT be matched
  // to the between list, then the start date does not have an 
  // uninterrupted path to the end date.
  if (a.count(_ == false) > 0) false
  else true
}
```

I just need to figure out how to index the start parameter so I can increase the value of it as the fold iterates over the between collection. Or it's possible that fold isn't what I'm supposed to use at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you need to stop your loop before you going through the whole collection, fold will not help (you can throw an exception to stop further processing, but, imho, it's bad way). You should go with tail recursion.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan Right. Scala is very `Exception` adverse; a characteristic that I'm glad to see was not inherited from Java.

Comment: You can replace `return status` with just `status`. `return` is only needed if you need to do a non-local exit, and is rarely used in Scala. Many Scala programmers literally never use `return`.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass previous DateTime item in accumulator:

```
val a = sortedBetween.foldLeft((List[Boolean](), start)) {
  case ((results, prev), current) => {
    ... calculate res here ...
    (results ++ List(res), current)
  }
}
```

But for this kind of check you better use sliding and forall combination:

```
 sortedBetween.sliding(2).forall {
   case List(prev,cur) => ..do the check here ..
 }
```

Also, note that you ingnoring the result of between sorting since IndexedSeq is immutable. Fix - use another val:

```
val sortedBetween = between.sortBy(_.getMillis())
```

Comment: IndexedSeq is immutable. Duh. Fixed that in the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think a fold isn't necessary, it's making things too hard.

Suppose you had the following functions:

```
private def normalizeDateTime( dt : DateTime ) : DateMidnight = ???

private def requiredBetweens( start : DateMidnight, end : DateMidnight ) : Seq[DateMidnight] = ???
```

Then you could write your function as follows:

```
def checkDate(start: DateTime, end: DateTime, between: IndexedSeq[DateTime]): Boolean = {
   val startDay = normalizeDateTime( start )
   val endDay = normalizeDateTime( end )
   val available = between.map( normalizeDateTime ).toSet
   val required = requiredBetweens( startDay, endDay ).toSet
   val unavailable = (required -- available)
   unavailable.isEmpty
}
```

Note that this function imposes no requirement as to the ordering of the betweens, treats the elements as a Set, only requiring that each day be available somewhere.

To implement `normalizeDateTime(...)` you might get away with something as simple as `dt.toDateMidnight`, but you should think a bit about `Chronology` and time zone issues. It's critical that `DateTime` objects that you mean to represent a day always normalize to the same `DateMidnight`.

To implement `requiredBetweens(...)`, you might consider using a `Stream` and `takeWhile(...)` for an elegant solution. You might want to require that `(end isAfter start)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use filter and then zip and take the difference, the dates should always be one day apart, so check they are all 1.

```
@ val ls = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)  // can use dates in the same way
ls: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

@ val ls2 = ls.filter { i => (2 < i) && (i < 6) }
ls2: Array[Int] = Array(3, 4, 5)

@ ls2.zip(ls2.drop(1))
res21: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((3, 4), (4, 5))

@ ls2.zip(ls2.drop(1)).map { case (x, y) => y-x }
res22: Array[Int] = Array(1, 1)

@ ls2.zip(ls2.drop(1)).map { case (x, y) => y-x }.forall { _ == 1 }
res23: Boolean = true
```

You also have to check that no dates are missing:

```
@ ls2.length == 6 - 2 - 1  // beware off-by-one errors
res25: Boolean = true
```

---

You *may* also be able to do this more simply by using the Range object:

```
@ ls2.zipAll(3 to 5 by 1, 0, 0).forall { case (x, y) => x == y }
res46: Boolean = true
```

This should work, but may need a slight tweak for DateTime...

```
@ val today = LocalDate.now
today: LocalDate = 2017-10-19

@ val a = (0 to 9).reverse.map { today.minusDays(_) }
a: collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[LocalDate] = Vector(2017-10-10, 2017-10-11, 2017-10-12, 2017-10-13, 2017-10-14, 2017-10-15, 2017-10-16, 2017-10-17, 2017-10-18, 2017-10-19)

@ a.zip(a.drop(1)).map { case (x, y) => x.until(y) }.forall { _ == Period.ofDays(1) }
res71: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with [tail recursion](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/annotation/tailrec.html). I'm using [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) from Java 8 for DateTime representation. Here is [online version on codepad.remoteinterview.io](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/HJVPWBRWYV):

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

object TailRecursionExample {
    def checkDate(start: ZonedDateTime, end: ZonedDateTime, 
                  between: Seq[ZonedDateTime]): Boolean = {

        // We have dates in range (inclusive) [start, end] with step = 1 day
        // All these days should be in between collection

        // set for fast lookup
        val set = between.toSet

        @tailrec
        def checkDate(curr: ZonedDateTime, iterations: Int): (Int, Boolean) = {
            if (curr.isAfter(end)) (iterations, true)
            else if (set.contains(curr)) checkDate(curr.plusDays(1), iterations + 1)
            else (iterations, false)

        }

        val (iterations, result) = if (start.isAfter(end)) 
            (0, false) 
        else 
            checkDate(start, 0)

        println(s"\tNum of iterations: $iterations")
        result
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        testWhenStartIsAfterEnd()
        println

        testWhenStartIsBeforeEnd()
        println

        testWhenStartIsBeforeEndButBetweenSkipOneDay()
        println
        ()
    }

    def testWhenStartIsAfterEnd(): Unit = {
        val start = ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(5)
        val end = ZonedDateTime.now()
        val between = (0 to 5).map(i => start.plusDays(i))

        verboseTest("testWhenStartIsAfterEnd", start, end, between)
    }

    def testWhenStartIsBeforeEnd(): Unit = {
        val start = ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(5)
        val end = ZonedDateTime.now()
        val between = (0 to 5).map(i => start.plusDays(i))

        verboseTest("testWhenStartIsBeforeEnd", start, end, between)
    }

    def testWhenStartIsBeforeEndButBetweenSkipOneDay(): Unit = {
        val start = ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(5)
        val end = ZonedDateTime.now()
        val between = (1 to 5).map(i => start.plusDays(i))

        verboseTest("testWhenStartIsBeforeEndButBetweenSkipOneDay", start, end, between)
    }

    def verboseTest(name: String, start: ZonedDateTime, end: ZonedDateTime, 
                  between: Seq[ZonedDateTime]): Unit = {
        println(s"$name:")
        println(s"\tStart: $start")
        println(s"\tEnd:   $end")
        println(s"\tBetween: ")
        between.foreach(t => println(s"\t\t$t"))
        println(s"\tcheckDate: ${checkDate(start, end, between)}")

    }  
}
```